# uidoc.copy does not work as expected

Tags: lotusscript

This works. After that, target has the content of source:

```
Call uidoc.GotoField("source")          
Call uidoc.SelectAll
Call uidoc.Copy                     
Call uidoc.GotoField("target")      
Call uidoc.Paste
```

Now, i would like to involve the user. He marks two words (a name) with mousecursor in the 'source' field. My intention is, to transfer this marked text to another field 'target'.

Notes documentation says that uidoc.copy takes text that is marked in edit mode.
Here an extract of original documentation:

> Copies the current selection in a document to the Clipboard. The
>   current selection can be anything on the document, such as text or
>   graphics.

This does not work, an error occurs. Error message: Only text can be pasted into this type of field:

```
Call uidoc.Copy                     
Call uidoc.GotoField("target")      
Call uidoc.Paste
```

All Fields are plain text.

Does anyone have another idea to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that a button in fact changes the focus to itself. That is the reason for that behaviour.

A possible solution is to use an Action which leaves the focus where it is.

Answer (score 0):

SO where is the question? uidoc.Copy just copies the whole document or nothing (depending on the cursor position). And both "contents" are not valid to be pasted into a Textfield.

But please: Don't use Copy + Paste in that context as the code will also fail, if document e.g. is not in Edit Mode.

Use Backend- Operations and then you will not depend on the right focus / editmode:

```
Call uidoc.Document.ReplaceItemValue( "Target" , uidoc.Document.GetItemValue( "Source" ) )
```

or even shorter (usind short hand notation):

```
uidoc.Document.Target = uidoc.Document.Source
```

Comment: I don't want to transfer the whole content. In that case you are right and i would have done it as you described.

Comment: The user is involed by marking a part of the text. I have edited the question to illustrate that in a better way.